# D3 - Best way to format data for multi-series column chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have 8 categories of data per facility and have created an interface to compare multiple facilities against each other for 'scoring'.  The categories are not related to each other in any sort of fashion.  The last element to add is a graph with the facility scores graphed against the other selected facilities.  When looking at the examples online, most data is in a CSV format but I will be swapping out values triggered by a drop-down list.

Example of data...

```
facility_score = {
    "a":20,
    "b":30,
    "c":1,
    "d":55, ...
}
```

I have a finished "[single](http://i.imgur.com/cZFjbhS.png)" facility done and want to expand upon it.

Comment: There's not really a "best" data format -- you'll have to do some preprocessing anyway and convert it to something that can be given directly to D3.

Comment: Trying to read up on the .data() method... Should my data be structured similar to the following? `scores = {facil_1:{"a":1, "b":24,...}, facil_2:{"a":33,"b":10,...},facil_3:{"a":45,"b":9,...}}`?

Comment: Now with proper formatting... `data = [{name:"facil_1",scores:{"a":1, "b":24,...}}, {name:"facil_2",scores:{"a":33,"b":10,...}},{name:"facil_3",scores:{"a":45,"b":9,...}}]`